# Looking for an erotic novel featuring a woman who is reborn over and over again until she can save her soulmate?

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm looking for a book that I read maybe 2 years ago that I really enjoyed but have forgotten the title of.

Here's what I remember:

- the initial romance takes place between a man and a woman in the past (a few hundred years ago in Britain or Scotland)
- the heroine is scared of the hero bc of his reputation so their first sexual encounter starts with him willingly tied to a chair (though she soon releases him)
- there is magic involved and the villain turns him into a statue (?) stuck in a tower
- the heroine has to reach him (and do something that I can't recall) to break the curse
- every time that she is killed trying, she is reborn to try again
- I think she has a guardian who is immortal (?) to help her, but he has to refind and reexplain everything to her each time
- in the current incarnation she is an expert in martial arts and finally manages to succeed

Comment: Sort of a medieval "Edge of Tomorrow" but with kinky sex? Sounds delightful.

Comment: Well, I didn't know I needed this in my life up until now. So, I'm also waiting for the answer.

Comment: Wow lol, try searching your bookshelves, this sounds interesting

Comment: You guys need to get out more.  @Jojoreads, I don't know of this one offhand (although admittedly, I'm pretty limited on romance/erotic to one fantasy author), and I'm trying to troll through TvTropes to find a close match but not finding one (*Deverry* looks close-ish?).  Anything you can add (a character name?) may be helpful.

Comment: Is she reincarnated as a different person or is this the same person in a time loop?